# Does FAQ have official errata power in Pathfinder Society Organized Play?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic, pathfinder-society, errata

According to FAQ, [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) and [Metamagic Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master/) traits don't allow their users to reduce spell level and have, say, a [Furious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/furious-spell-metamagic) Magic Missile as a 0 level spell (allowing to cast it at-will), or [Intensified](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) Fireball as a 2nd level spell.

However, it has not been introduced as errata, and the text of those traits remains unchanged. Does this ruling presented in the FAQ have the official judgement power and change the way the feats work?

While any reasonable GM should definitely not allow such a cheese, I am asking from a point of Pathfinder Society Organized Play, where GMs have to play exactly as the rules say.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36364/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its important to note that the trait "Metamagic Master" does not exist anywhere in Pathfinder material. Its called [Wayang Spellhunter](http://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wayang%20Spellhunter) in Pathfinder material. The d20pfsrd had it listed as Metamagic Master because they were asked to remove anything specific to the Golarion setting from the site, so they renamed Wayang Spellhunter to Metamagic Master. Archives of Nethys are now the official Paizo srd, and is permitted to use Golarion-specific names and information.

In a few different places I found people saying it was permitted for them in PFS, or that Paizo had an official ruling stating it was allowed, but no link or anything so I can't be sure. There is an [entry in the FAQ about Magical Lineage](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qns), and it says the trait cannot reduce a spell below its original level. As mentioned, the Archives of Nethys are Paizo's official SRD, and on the site it notes which traits are PFS approved. Both [Magical Lineage](http://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Magical%20Lineage) and [Wayang Spellhunter](http://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wayang%20Spellhunter) have the stamp of approval (hover over the round icon to the left of the trait name and it reads "PFS Legal").

Furthermore, I'm reasonably confident this combination isn't the threat it seems. In both cases, you are limited to a specific spell, and both are contingent on using a metamagic feat, which you have to spend feats on. Now you are in the hole two traits and a feat just to get this setup. Sure, you could sling Magic Missiles all day long, but you've spent all that to spam one not especially powerful spell. Casting an intensified Fireball at 2nd level would be alright, I guess, but only useful once you are over level 10, and again, spending a pair of talents plus a feat (and not an especially useful feat in general) to buff just that one spell and not even get a payoff till level 11 is not really a threat to game balance. Other examples I've found of this combination seem similarly gimmicky and not really game-breaking.

In the absence of any ruling otherwise and with both traits officially approved, I think you are in the clear.

Comment: Well, spamming Magic Missiles at-will could be used at the first level before you rebuild your character for free, and casting Fireballs as a 2nd level spell is always good, no matter the level. However, I'd like to make sure that your answer is "FAQ has no official power regarding that"

Comment: I've stated that both traits are individually approved for Pathfinder Society and there is no official FAQ I can find (or hear referenced) against the combo, and even have anecdotal evidence people have used it in Society characters. Not sure where I'm unclear.

Comment: As far as the combo itself, it's useful, just not overpowered. It's a specialization, and comes with trade-offs. In my opinion it's probably not worth the cost, but even if it is, it's not the kind of thing they need to outlaw.

Comment: Paizo typically just doesn't issue errata for it's smaller books—like *Dragon Empires Primer*, the source of Waywang Spellhunter (né Metamagic Master)—, preferring to focus its FAQ efforts on bigger books like *Ultimate Campaigns.*

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, the errata is used in organized play.

[From the PFS FAQ:](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fq#v5748eaic9qy5)

> **Are official blog post FAQ's or Errata updates legal for Pathfinder Society Organized Play?**
>
> Yes. Please follow these clarifications.

<sub>Note: That special character is copied over from the FAQ, please do not edit the post to remove it.</sub>

Comment: One should actually wonder if FAQ can grant itself power. Anyway, that's a lot closer to the official answer.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy It stands for Frequently Asked Questions, so one would assume that it's a list of things that are frequently asked. Thus they put the answers up for ease.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I am certain you could *have* that argument, but I'm also fairly certain that Society GM—in whose adventure you want your character to participate—would win that argument. `:-)` (And, william porter, I feel like I'm losing my mind: *What* special character?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan This one "", it shows up as a box for me. Unsure of what it is.

Comment: Honestly, in that comment above after where it says *This one* on my end there's literally *no* character—not even an empty space—between the quotation marks. (I even copied & pasted both this answer and that comment into *Word* to make sure.)